# Python: String index out of range

Tags: python, string, indexing, range, syntax-error

I have had a look at a lot of previous questions put up, but still couldn't find anything that'll help me here.
Here's a code I wrote to Reverse a sentence.
I could have used split() function, but I tried to do without it anyways.

```
s='abcdef ghij klmn op qrst uv w xy z'
s=s[::-1]
print s
j=0
p=''
while(j<len(s)):
    a=''
    while(s[j]!=''):
        a=a+s[j]
        j+=1
    p.append(a[::-1])
    j+=1
print p
```

It gives me a string index out of range error in the while bracket. Why?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Your code isn't very readable. Consider using more descriptive names, and more whitespace around operators.

Comment: Will `while(s[j] != '')` ever evaluate to false while `j` less than `len(S)`? If not, when `j` gets to equal `len(S)` .. it'll crash!!

Comment: You create a lot of intermediate strings. You should work with lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is with this inner loop:

```
while(s[j]!=''):
    a=a+s[j]
    j+=1
```

This loop allows `j` to exceed the length of `s`, you probably want to add an additional condition here to prevent this (I also removed the unnecessary parentheses):

```
while j < len(s) and s[j] != '':
    a=a+s[j]
    j+=1
```

Comment: Thank you. And I realised another quite stupid error. I was trying to append to a string. :)

Answer (score 2):

Because in the second while loop you're incrementing `j` without checking if you're at the end yet.

Also, `s[j]!=''` will always be true for strings. If you can use the index operator on a string it means that there are characters. Otherwise there are none.

For example:

```
s = ''
s[0]  # IndexError, there are no characters so there can be no index

s = 'x'
s[0]  # Will be x and s[1] will give the same error as above
```

---

A little simpler version of your code (not really Pythonic, would be nicer to use lists and use `' '.join()`):

```
s = 'abcdef ghij klmn op qrst uv w xy z'
print s

p = ''
i = 0
word = ''
while i < len(s):
    c = s[i]
    if c == ' ':
        if p:
            p = word + ' ' + p
        else:
            p = word

        word = ''
    else:
        word += c
    i += 1

print p
```

And the clean/simple Pythonic version with split:

```
s = 'abcdef ghij klmn op qrst uv w xy z'
print s
p = ' '.join(s.split()[::-1])
print p
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this: -

```
s='abcdef ghij klmn op qrst uv w xy z'
s=s[::-1]
print s
j=0
p=[]
while(j<len(s)):
    a=''
    while(j<len(s) and s[j]!=' '):
        a=a+s[j]
        j+=1
    p.append(a[::-1])
    j+=1
print ' '.join(p)
```

Comment: Exactly. Only, I wasn't aware of the join function. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(s[j]!=''):
        a=a+s[j]
        j+=1
```

Here's is the problem.. Your last character is `z`.. When it reaches there, your while condition is true.. And it tries increment `j` to next index.. Which is out of bound..

You can probably move this condition also to your `outer` while loop.. Because you need to check both the conditions at the same time... Both the conditions must be true in your case..